# linode/lamp unable to map files using -v parameter

Tags: docker, lamp, linode

I am trying to run my own local LAMP stack using Docker Toolbox and linode/lamp however I am running into some difficulty when mapping the files to the virtual directory in the container. Here is the command I am running:

```
docker run -p 4000:80 -t -i -v /z/html:/var/www/example.com/public_html linode/lamp /bin/bash
```

This command correctly maps the directories however it seems that the files are totally independent. i.e. creating an `index.php` file in `/z/html` is not reflected in the virtual directory `public_html` and vice versa.

Forgive me if this is a very basic question, I am quite new to Docker.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. thats weird . .because i just tried it. .and it work fine using same exact command u'are using. .except im using `$PWD/testDir/:` as mount point to test sync host directory and container directory, i tried to create new file from within container and vise versa. .it works fine.

assuming that `/z/html/` directory of yours is correct directory, than it should be work.

maybe u can try to using another mount point directory

Comment: I have tried using a different mount point and it also shows an empty folder. Additionally, I have tried using a compose.yml file to sync the directories and the effect is the same.